# How to initialize an instance using pickle()?

Tags: python

I want to define a class that is able to populate itself reading from the serialized data of another instance. Here's the simplified code:

```
class MyClass(list):

    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        if kwargs.has_key('fdata'):
            f = open(kwargs['fdata'],'r')
            self = pickle.load(f)
            print len(self)    #prints 320          
            f.close()              

    ...

a = MyClass(fdata='data.dat')
print len(a)    #prints 0
```

This is the output I obtain:

```
320
0
```

The problem I have is that the instance returned is always empty, even though I am able to read all the elements inside `__init__()` What can be causing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assigning to `self` inside a method simply rebinds the local name `self` to a different object.  Assignments to bare names in Python can never *modify* any object – they just rebind names.

Why don't you use the straight-forward

```
with open("data.dat") as f:
    a = pickle.load(f)
```

instead of constructing a new class?  If you don't like this, wrap this in a function, but it's not that useful to put this code into `__init__()`.

There are other ways to achieve the same effect.  Probably the best way to achieve exactly what you are trying is to overwrite `__new__()` instead of `__init__()` – `__new__()` is called *before* the new instance is constructed, so you can simply return the unpickled instance instead of having to modify an already constructed one.

Answer (score 3):

`self` is a regular local variable in Python. You can't use `self = other` to make an object "become" something else, you'll just reassign the local. You'll have to restore the attributes one-by-one, or use something like:

```
self.__dict__ = pickle.load(f).__dict__
```

(I haven't tested that last line, it might well make your kittens explode.)

Comment: Assigning to `__dict__` to copy the object state works in the (common) case that you derive from `object` and don't define `__slots__`.

Comment: `self.__dict__.update()` might be a "safer" option, but then you could be left with things that were removed from the pickled data for a good reason...